# Non deterministic gas usage of the same function

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-limit, revert-opcode

## Environment

`Truffle v4.1.8 
node 10.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;`

## Issue

I'm calling the `claimRefund` function on my smart contract using metamask. When calling the function with **37081** gas limit at **20 gwei** gas price, the transaction spends **36924** gas and gets reverted with EVM Revert.

If I change params to **58080** gas limit at **20 gwei** gas price, the transaction passes spending **24721** gas.

The code is shown below:

```
   /**
   * @param investor Investor address
   */
  function refund(address investor) public {
    require(state == State.Refunding);
    uint256 depositedValue = deposited[investor];
    deposited[investor] = 0;
    investor.transfer(depositedValue);
    emit Refunded(investor, depositedValue);
  }
  }


  function claimRefund() public {
    require(isFinalized);
    require(!goalReached());

    vault.refund(msg.sender);
  }
```

## Question

How is it possible that the same call results in a different gas spent amount? Also, how can a function fail after spending more gas and pass after spending less gas?

Comment: Showin the code for `goalReached()` would also help.

Comment: Are you testing against ganache or some other testnet like ropsten? What version of the compiler are you using? There was a bug in solc that caused some odd behavior when estimating gas use https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3687 and this https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/82p78k/two_identical_arguments_for_function_call_one/dvc8bbh/.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the amount of gas you need to supply is sometimes greater than the amount that actually gets deducted.

This happens because when you clear storage, as you do when you delete the balance from `deposited[investor]`, this causes a gas refund which will be subtracted from your total deducted gas. However, this refund isn't credited until the end of the transaction, so it can't be used to pay for the steps that follow it, in this case your `transfer` call and your `Refunded` event.